# Are Snoke bodyguards old Jedi trainees?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In the latest movie, it was mentioned that when Kylo Ren burned Lukes trainee temple, that he left with some of the trainees and killed all the rest.

While there is no mention (as far as I'm aware) of where those other Jedi trainees are, could it be possible that those are/were snoke bodyguards?

It would make sense in the way that Snoke let Kylo Ren come to him (and therefore with the rest of the surviving trainees). 
But of course it isn't really mentioned in the movie.

So any ideas?

Comment: That was my thought, especially since they weren't instantly slaughtered.

Comment: But... why would Jedi trainees throw away their lightsabers and start fighting with swords and knives?

Comment: They most likely fall in the lineage of the guards that Palpatine had protected him

Comment: No, they're action-figures thrown in for making more money.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is assumed by some (including myself) that these are the Knights of Ren. There are mentioned and make a brief appearance in *The Force Awakens*:

[image: The Knights of Ren]

Here's an article that goes into more detail: https://www.inverse.com/article/39523-star-wars-last-jedi-knights-of-ren-luke-students-jedi-kylo

Comment: Agreed. That fits nicely. I also take it that the Knights of Ren are the same Jedi trainees, but that's a tenuous link too far.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's debatable, not that The Knight of Ren are the former Jedi trainees/Padawans, but rather in the sense that I do think the Knights of Ren served Snoke some purpose, but I'm not sure if they are really his personal body guards since *The Last Jedi* introduced Praetorian Guards to play that role. If the Knight's of Ren were his body guards, then why were they not in the throne room???

[image: Praetorian]

In Addition The Knights of **Ren** seem more like a religious cult or military order not unlike Star Wars' own version of *Knights of erRENt* (Chivalrous **Errand Boys**) or "Ren" could also be short for REN-aissance suggesting a something like a revival or more literally "rebirth", which would go with the undisclosed mythology (Kylo's and Rey's raw power and force dynamics or concept: The Force AWAKENS)) and Kylo Ren's [lightsaber design](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kylo_Ren%27s_lightsaber)

> The lightsaber, based on **an ancient design dating back to the Great
>   Scourge of Malachor,** contained a cracked Kyber crystal, requiring it
>   to have lateral vents on either side of the handle in order to divert
>   the extra heat generated by the crystal.

Many people speculate that The Knights of Ren may be an advancement/evolution/expansion on [Acolytes of the Beyond](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Acolytes_of_the_Beyond), since Kylo Ren's (and possibly Snoke's) obsession with Darth Vader and/or the Skywalker bloodline matches with the ideology. (ie: *"That lightsaber, it belongs to me." - Kylo Ren to Rey TFA* )